# Random to sequential script

Tags: javascript

This is part of a script. It generates words randomly using the "Math.random" function.

I would like the words to be generated sequentially, as I ordered them. Is there a string to replace Math.random with another word like "Math.sequential" ??

```
chosenCategory = categories[Math.floor(Math.random() * categories.length)];
word = chosenCategory[Math.floor(Math.random() * chosenCategory.length)];
```

I tried to remove this part Math.random() * but the script stopped working this way.

Comment: Can you share an example of the expected output? I'm not sure I understand what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: If you don't want them to be random, you don't need any function. Just use a variable to hold the current index in the array, and increment it before getting the next element.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Use global variables to hold the current indexes in the arrays. Increment these variables to go through the arrays sequentially.

The code below will go through all the words in the first category, then the words in the second category, and so on, wrapping back to the first category when it reaches the end.

```js
let catIndex = 0;
let wordIndex = 0;

function getNextWord() {
  if (wordIndex >= categories[catIndex].length) {
    catIndex++;
    wordIndex = 0;
  }
  if (catIndex >= categories.length) { // wrap around
    catIndex = 0;
  }
  let word = categories[catIndex][wordIndex];
  wordIndex++;
  return word;
}
```